# Avoid third table multiplying results

Tags: sql, database, join

I have three tables.

**Defect**: Main table used to store defects found.

**FollowUp**: Table that stores followups to a specific Defect.

**Defect_Attach**: Related table used all photo attachments for Defects and FollowUps.

[image]

**How can I get dates for all photo attachments?**

Some of these photos were taken for a defect, then at a later date, more photos were related to the defect during a followup.

The results I'm trying to get would look something like this:

[image]

or

[image]

So far my query looks like this:

```
SELECT d.GUID
        ,p.ATTACHMENTID
        ,p.REL_OBJECTID
        ,p.CONTENT_TYPE
        ,p.ATT_NAME
        ,p.DATA_SIZE
        ,d.DateObserved as 'Defect Date'
        --,f.DateObserved as 'FollowUp Date'
FROM [ECIMUSR].[DEFECT__ATTACH] p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ECIMUSR.DEFECT d on d.ObjectID = p.REL_OBJECTID
    --LEFT JOIN ECIMUSR.FOLLOWUP f on f.DefectGUID = d.GUID
WHERE 
    d.GUID = '{E511EA70-F5E5-11E4-8189-6C3BE50ED71F}'
    ORDER BY [Defect Date]
```

But as soon as I try joining my third table (FOLLOWUP), my results multiply.

**UPDATE:**
Results:

```
SELECT p.ATT_NAME
        ,d.DateObserved as 'Defect Date'
        --,f.DateObserved as 'FollowUp Date'
FROM [ECIMUSR].[DEFECT__ATTACH] p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ECIMUSR.DEFECT d on d.ObjectID = p.REL_OBJECTID
    --LEFT JOIN ECIMUSR.FOLLOWUP f on f.DefectGUID = d.GUID
WHERE 
    d.GUID = '{E511EA70-F5E5-11E4-8189-6C3BE50ED71F}'
    ORDER BY [Defect Date]
```

[image]

**Joining THIRD Table:**

```
SELECT p.ATT_NAME
        ,d.DateObserved as 'Defect Date'
        ,f.DateObserved as 'FollowUp Date'
FROM [ECIMUSR].[DEFECT__ATTACH] p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ECIMUSR.DEFECT d on d.ObjectID = p.REL_OBJECTID
    LEFT JOIN ECIMUSR.FOLLOWUP f on f.DefectGUID = d.GUID
WHERE 
    d.GUID = '{E511EA70-F5E5-11E4-8189-6C3BE50ED71F}'
    ORDER BY [Defect Date]
```

[image]

Comment: What is your DBMS?  And what results are you currently getting (I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "multiply")

Comment: Do you have multiple rows in Followup per any given photo?

Comment: If one defect can have more than one follow up, what do you want to join on to your existing query?  The most recent followup?  The first follow up?  Or some summary statistics, such as number of follow-ups, date of first, date of last, etc.

Comment: @Andrew That's what the symbol with an empty circle and three prongs means.

Comment: @capdragon - Yes, that's understood; but what do you Want to be joined on to your results?  One photo is for one Defect and that Defect can have Multiple follow ups.  Yet you want to not "multiply up" your results, so you *can't* join on to *all* of the multiple follow ups.  You could join and get just the Latest follow up (ignoring all the rest)?  Or the First follow up (again, ignoring all the rest)?  Or a count of how many follow ups there have been (an aggregated view of all your followups, that fits in to 1 row per defect).  You need to specify what information you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: @MatBailie - Please see my "The results I'm trying to get would look something like this:" section.

Comment: But what are the rules that you want to apply for picking One follow up?  You have one defect in your list (from the WHERE clause) on the 19th December.  That defect has 5 photos and 3 follow up dates.  Your example, however, shows ***4*** follow up dates.  And there is no empirical way to determine which follow up should be associated to which photo.  *(One photo has no date in its name, two photos share the same dates as each other and with One follow up date, and the dates in the other two photos although the same don't appear as follow up dates.)*

Comment: What about this?  Column1 = Defect Date, same date every time.  Column2 = PhotoNames, in alphabetical order.  Column3 = Followup dates in time order.  The PhotoName will have nothing to do with the Followup date, they will be next to each other just by coincidence.  And because there are 5 photos and 3 dates, there will be 2 nulls in the followup date column (next to the last 2 photos).

Comment: @MatBailie - I see, so what you're saying is that what I want is not possible. I was afraid of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    d.DateObserved     AS defect_date,
    p.ATT_NAME         AS photo_name,
    f.DateObserved     AS follow_up_date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REL_OBJECTID
                               ORDER BY ATT_NAME)   AS ordinal
    FROM
        ECIMUSR.DEFECT__ATTACH
)
    p
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DefectGUID
                               ORDER BY DateObserved)   AS ordinal
    FROM
        ECIMUSR.FOLLOWUP
)
    f
        ON  f.DefectGUID = p.REL_OBJECTID
        AND f.ordinal    = p.ordinal
RIGHT JOIN
    ECIMUSR.DEFECT    d
        ON  d.ObjectID = COALESCE(f.DefectGUID, p.REL_OBJECTID)
```

Would give something like...

```
 defect_date | photo_name                  | follow_up_date
-------------+-----------------------------+----------------
  2014-12-19 | photo1.jpg                  | 2015-01-16
  2014-12-19 | PhotoFollowUp1_20150117.jpg | 2015-03-19
  2014-12-19 | PhotoFollowUp1_20150324.jpg | 2015-04-17
  2014-12-19 | PhotoFollowUp1_20150417.jpg | NULL
  2014-12-19 | PhotoFollowUp2_20150324.jpg | NULL
```

The photo names and the follow up dates have nothing to do with each others.  they're just in alphabetical order with gaps if one list is longer than the other.

Comment: (+1) Unfortunately, I need the dates to match up with the photo name. You're saying there is no way? I was afraid of this. It makes sense. I was hoping someone would know of a way that I couldn't think of.

Comment: I'll give you credit for the answer. While it's not what I wanted, you've told me what I need to hear, "it's not possible".